# PHPStan cast to more specific array shape

Tags: phpstan, array-shape

In my code, I call a method whose return value is typed as follows:

```
/**
 * @return array<int, array<string,mixed>>
 */
public function fetchAllAssociative(): array;
```

The subtype `array<string, mixed>` describes the database record in a generic way. I know exactly what this database record looks like so I want to be more specific in documenting the method:

```
/**
 * @return array<int, array{id: int, firstName: string, lastName: string}>
 */
public function getAllUsers(): array
{
  return $this->userRepository->fetchAllAssociative();
}
```

However, PHPStan complains that I should type my methods exactly as `fetchAllAssociative`:

`Method UserRepository::getAllUsers() should return array<int, array{id: int, firstName: string, lastName: string}> but returns array<int, array<string, mixed>>.`

Is there a way to cast it? My workaround is to introduce a new variable and use the `@var` tag but I don't really like it (other static code analysis tools don't like it as well)

```
/**
 * @return array<int, array{id: int, firstName: string, lastName: string}>
 */
public function getAllUsers(): array
{
  /**
   * @var array<int, array{id: int, firstName: string, lastName: string}> $data
   */
  $data = $this->userRepository->fetchAllAssociative();

  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Did you read this? https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/narrowing-types

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar. Unfortunately, I think adding `// @phpstan-ignore-next-line` to the implementation is the only other thing you can do.

In Typescript, this is basically equivalent to asserting that `any` is `User`. Typically this would happen in a "makeUser" function the moment you get and validate the data (e.g. from a database or an http request) so that you can minimize your `data as unknown as User` usages. Otherwise, this is the consequence.

So, general advise to anyone else running into this, start with your repositories and really make it a point to avoid `array<mixed>` and `mixed`, cause it's going to quickly trickle throughout your system.